# Can I fast if I have stomach and digestive issues?

Tags: sawm

I am severally underweight due to digestive problems.durin ramzan i only eat a little and feel full even cant drink enough water.. I not diagnose with proper disease Should i have to perform fasting or not?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that we are not fatwa site. You should know best whether you are able to fast or not else you should consult a physician.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, fasting is considered one of the Five Pillars and is an obligatory religious practice.
If you have stomach and digestive issues that may make it difficult for you to fast, you should consult with your doctor and a trusted Islamic scholar or imam to determine if it is safe for you to fast. In some cases, it may be recommended that you do not fast, or that you delay or modify your fasting to accommodate your medical condition.

> Acid reflux is something that happens involuntarily. A person may feel some acidity or bitter taste in his esophagus but it does not
> reach the mouth. In this case, it is not regarded as one of the things
> that invalidate the fast, because it does not come out of the mouth.
>
> But if it comes out to the mouth, then in that case it comes under the ruling on reflux or vomiting.
> [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/40696/does-acid-reflux-break-your-fast)

Ibn Hazm said in al-Muhalla (4/225):

> “Reflux that comes out of the throat does not invalidate the fast, so
> long as the person does not deliberately swallow it back after it
> reaches the mouth when he is able to expel it.”

If you are unable to fast due to a medical condition, you may be required to make up the missed fasts at a later time or to feed the poor in place of the missed fasts. This is known as fidyah, and is a way for individuals who are unable to fast to still participate in the spiritual and religious aspects of Ramadan.